# JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 6 (char 6)

Tags: python, json

getting error while executing below python code:

```
import json
json_str = """
  {
  “AircraftKey”: “AircraftKey_data”,
  “Latitude”: 100,
  “Longitude”: 200,
  “FuelQuantityLeft”: “FuelQuantityLeft_data”,
  “FuelQuantityRight”: “FuelQuantityRight_data”,
  “TKSLeft”: “TKSLeft_data”,
  “TKSRight”: “TKSRight_data”,
  “OxygenQuantity”: “OxygenQuantity_data”,
  “OilTemperature”: “OilTemperature_data”,
  “Battery1Voltage”: “Battery1Voltage_data”,
  “Battery2Voltage”: “Battery2Voltage_data”,
  “ReceivedDate”: 20190901,
  “LastUpdatedDate”: 20190901
   }"""
data = json.loads(json_str)
```

Comment: Actually these are different `“ and "`. So change all your double quotes with `"` this.

Comment: Which error you got?

Comment: The same code is working in interpreter

Comment: As the message states, your "json_str" is not valid json (cf VikasP comment).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line just before `json.loads`:

```
json_str = json_str.replace('“', '"').replace('”', '"')
```